# `sap.m.FeedListItem`: icon does not change after initial rendering

Tags: sapui5

I have a master and a detail view. In the master view, you can switch between pages. Everything works fine. However, when you change from *Projects* to *Contact* / *Impress* (or vice versa), the icons of the three first feed list items are not updated, although the property correctly changes. I am sure that this worked with an earlier version. What am I doing wrong?

Code of the page:

```xml
<Page>
  <List items="{feed}">
    <FeedListItem
      icon="{icon}"
      showIcon="{=typeof ${icon}!=='undefined'}"
      iconActive="false"
      text="{text}"
      convertLinksToAnchorTags="All"
      modelContextChange=".handleModelContextChange"
    />
  </List>
</Page>
```

The affected site can be found here: http://marius-spix.de/

I filed [GitHub bug #2079](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2079) with a similar `FeedListItem` issue a long time ago, but it seems to be unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know. I just created a bunch of issues related to the `sap.m.FeedListItem` on GitHub ([[1]](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3259), [[2]](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3258), [[3]](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3260)).

<del>Since most of the mentioned bugs are caused by the [commit `454a41c`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/454a41c8b7034c673a9c34b92921ced54b7bdce5), which came with UI5 v1.88, remaining at one of the lower [versions supported by OpenUI5](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html) or [SAPUI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/versionoverview.html) could be a temporary solution until the fixes are available.</del>

**Update:** the [fixes](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/8aba9a495979a9a97ba2ae68273939b7488d1082) are now merged with the master branch and will be available in the upcoming UI5 version 1.92 and patch releases for older versions.

Comment: Thank you. I note that the CSS class .sapMBtnIcon  is replaced by .sapFAvatarIcon which requires migration of old themes. But otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: In my case, I replaced ```.sapMBtnIcon{color:#348718!important}``` (accent color) with ```.sapFAvatarCircle{background-color:#e8f6ee!important} .sapFAvatarIcon{color:#666!important}``` (header text color on header background color) for a nicer look.

Comment: @spixi CSS styles are **not** part of the public API contracts and will thus change constantly over the version history, which is also the reason why UI5 explicitly warns that Fiori applications should **not** depend on them: _> CSS generated by SAPUI5 is not part of the public API_ ([src](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796)). But of course, for a personal homepage, the styles can be modified as much as needed, but the app author needs to write visual tests before doing an upgrade.